# How to query last 'n' number of records from a table?

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

I'm using an Azure mobile service with a C# back end for my app, but I'm not sure how to query the last 16 records that were added to the DB.

I've come across the statement, and I thought that could query the "last" 16 records but it doesn't:

```
var result = await itemModelTable
                .Take(16)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Does anyone have an idea how to form this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of `Last`, You need to order your collection and then use `Take` like:

```
var result = await itemModelTable
                .OrderByDescending(r=> r.SomeField)
                .Take(16)
                .ToListAsync();
```

For "Last", you need to use `OrderByDescending` and then use `Take`.

If no order is specified, then the records returned could be in any order. Same like SQL `Select` statement without `order by` clause.